# CUDA coalesced memory access speed depending on word size

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I have a CUDA program where one warp needs to access (for example) 96 bytes of global memory.

It properly aligns the memory location and lane indices such that the access is coalesced and done in a single transaction.

The program could do the access using 12 lanes each accessing a uint8_t. Alternately it would use 6 lanes accessing a uint16_t, or 3 lanes accessing a uint32_t.

Is there a performance difference between these alternatives, is the access faster if each thread accesses a smaller amount of memory?

When the amounts of memory each warp needs to access vary, is there a benefit in optimizing it such that the threads are made to access smaller units (16bit or 8bit) when possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing how the data will be used once in registers it is hard to state the optimal option. For almost all GPUs the performance difference between these options will likely be very small.

NVIDIA GPU L1 supports returning either 64 bytes/warp (CC5.*,6.*) or 128 bytes/warp (CC3.*, CC7.*) returns from L1. As long as the size <= 32 bits per thread then the performance should be very similar.

In CC 5.*/6.* there may be a small performance benefit to reduce the number of predicated true threads (prefer larger data). The L1TEX unit breaks global access into 4 x 8 thread requests. If full groups of 8 threads are predicated off then a L1TEX cycle is saved. Write back to the register file takes the same number of cycles. The grouping order of threads is not disclosed.

Good practice is to write a micro-benchmark. The CUDA profilers have numerous counters for different portions of the L1TEX path to help see the difference.